# sed - find a string with special characters and replace in a file

Tags: python, perl, sed, replace, find

I have a difficulty in searching a string in a file that has multiple special characters and replace the whole line with some text having special characters.

search string in a file

```
a.bb.cc[hk].ccm[*].nib[*].gion[*].der[*].sam[*].ant[ck].sant[*].tags[*].rmp
```

replace with

```
dde.be.cc[hk].com[*].nib[*].gion[*].der[*].sam[*].ant[ck].sant[*].tags[*].rmp=200
```

tried using linux sed but that needs to escape all these special characters and I do not want to do. These special characters might change for other strings.

```
perl -e "s/$to_replace/$replace_with/g" -pi /tmp/l1 
sed -i -e "s/'$to_replace'/'$replace_with'/g" /tmp/l1
```

both these failed as they expecting escape characters.

Any help here will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what are `$to_replace` and `$replace_with`?

Comment: to_replace is a variable having the string that needs to be replaced.
$to_replace = "a.bb.cc[hk].ccm[*].nib[*].gion[*].der[*].sam[*].ant[ck].sant[*].tags[*].rmp" 
$replace_with = "dde.be.cc[hk].com[*].nib[*].gion[*].der[*].sam[*].ant[ck].sant[*].tags[*].rmp=200"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\Q` and `\E` escape sequences to disable pattern metacharacters, i.e. just treat them like regular characters to match.  Equivalently, you could just place your search string inside the `quotemeta` function and then perform `s|$search|$replace|g` which would now work as you expect.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $search = 'a.bb.cc[hk].ccm[*].nib[*].gion[*].der[*].sam[*].ant[ck].sant[*].tags[*].rmp';
my $replace = 'dde.be.cc[hk].com[*].nib[*].gion[*].der[*].sam[*].ant[ck].sant[*].tags[*].rmp=200';

my $txt = <<EOTXT;
This is some text.
The next line needs replacing...
Inside here: < a.bb.cc[hk].ccm[*].nib[*].gion[*].der[*].sam[*].ant[ck].sant[*].tags[*].rmp >
More normal text
EOTXT

# perldoc perlre
#  s|...|...|   substitute
# \Q ... \E     quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till \E
#
# modifiers:
# s             treat string as single line
# g             global

$txt =~ s|\Q$search\E|$replace|sg;
print $txt;
```

**output**

```
This is some text.
The next line needs replacing...
Inside here: < dde.be.cc[hk].com[*].nib[*].gion[*].der[*].sam[*].ant[ck].sant[*].tags[*].rmp=200 >
More normal text
```